# Floating Action Button changes size on multi-window

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, floating-action-button

I've noticed when using the [design library's Floating Action Button](https://developer.android.com/training/material/design-library.html#CreateFAB) that when the app is put in [multi-window mode](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/multi-window.html), the FAB is automatically resized to its "mini" size. Other apps such as Gmail share the same behaviour.

As opposed to that, my own UI elements and buttons don't change size. I set a fixed dp size for them, and they stay with that same size.

Is there any design recommendation to provide smaller UI elements when the app is in multi-window mode? Should one listen for app size changes and resize buttons depending on it? Or is this behaviour only recommended for the FAB button?